# Hyperledger Fabric: Setup two peers of same Org on different physical Machines

Tags: docker, ubuntu, hyperledger-fabric

I have set up a blockchain test network on an Ubuntu 20.04 machine. The network was built and set up according to the fabric-samples Repo https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples. Fabric version is 2.3.0 and Fabric CA version is 1.4.9. My goal now is to set up a second peer for the same Org on another machine to integrate the peer into my existing network. So that I can also install my smartcontract/chaincode there and test my queries on the second peer as well.

**Short summary:**

1. Ubuntu 20.04 machine with one peer, one orderer and one ca server each for peer and orderer. Runs at an internet provider
2. ubuntu 20.04 machine with one peer. Is only accessible via our company VPN, because the machine is in our company network.

I have now made 3 different attempts to build or extend the network.

**1. Attempt**

In the first attempt I set up the network already described above on the 1st Ubuntu machine, created a channel and installed/deployed my chaincode/smartcontract. At the same time I also generated the "Crypto-Materials" for the second peer via the Fabric-CA server from the organization "Org 1".

Then I copied the previously generated "Crypto-Materials" to the 2nd Ubuntu server. After that, using my docker-compose, I started the second peer.
Then I tried to get the peer into the channel using the following commands:

```
#!/bin/bash

joinChannel() {
    ##### Umgebungvariablen setzen #####

    # Frage wo die configtx.yaml liegt und setze die Umgebungvariable FABRIC_CFG_PATH
    #read -p "Wo liegt die core.yaml für den peer der dem Channel hinzugefügt werden soll: " configtxpath

export CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID="Org1MSP"
export CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=$PWD/organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.actiware.com/peers/peer1.org1.actiware.com/tls/ca.cert
export CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=$PWD/organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.actiware.com/users/Admin@org1.actiware.com/msp
export CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=localhost:8051
export FABRIC_CFG_PATH=$PWD/newPeer/config

BLOCKFILE=$PWD/channel-artifacts/awchannel.block

echo "use core.yaml from: $FABRIC_CFG_PATH"
echo "Use core peer localmspid: $CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID"
echo "USe tls rootcertfiel: $CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE"
echo "Use Mspconfigpath: $CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH"
echo "Use adress: $CORE_PEER_ADDRESS"

echo "channel fetch genesis block"
peer channel fetch config -o [IP OF 1. Ubuntu Machine]:7050 --ordererTLSHostnameOverride orderer.actiware.com -c awchannel --tls --cafile $PWD/organizations/ordererOrganizations/actiware.com/orderers/orderer.actiware.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.actiware.com-cert.pem

##### peer dem channel hinzufügen #####

    # Frage wo die block datei ist
    #read -p "Wo liegt die channel_name.block Datei?: " blockfile

    DELAY=3
    MAX_RETRY=5
    local rc=1
    local COUNTER=1
    ## Sometimes Join takes time, hence retry
    while [ $rc -ne 0 -a $COUNTER -lt $MAX_RETRY ]; do
        sleep $DELAY
        peer channel join -b $BLOCKFILE
        res=$?
        let rc=$res
        COUNTER=$(expr $COUNTER + 1)
    done
}

joinChannel
```

And got the following error after that on orderer docker container:
[Logs of Orderer Docker Container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQUcl.png)

And this failur of the peer docker container on the 2. Ubuntu Maschine:
[Logs of Peer Container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ig7PP.png)

I did not get this error resolved. I guess because Docker gives the containers their own IP's again, the Docker containers from the orderer on the 1st Ubuntu machine and the peer from the 2nd Ubuntu machine can't communicate directly with each other.

**2. Attempt**

On the second try I then tried to set it up natively on the servers.
Restarted with the 1st Ubuntu machine I then instead of setting the configuration parameters via environment variables.
I set these directly in the files provided for it (core.yaml, orderer.yaml and config.tx).
Of course, I only set the ones that were also set as environment variables in the docker-compose files.
Of course, the same goes for the fabric-ca servers and their respective configuration files.
Then I started the fabric-ca servers natively and generated the "crypto material" using the registerEnroll.sh script.
Then I started the orderer and peer using the environment variable FABRIC_CFG_PATH.
Last but not least, I then wanted to create the channel and install the chaincode as in the Docker attempt.
I was able to successfully create the channel on the orderer and the peer was able to join it.
However, when I tried to install the chaincode via the CLI commands with peer chaincode lifecycle I got an error:
[CC install Error on Ubuntu Machine 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdQYX.png)

**3. Attempt**

Then in the last attempt I wanted clarity if it wasn't due to some configuration error. So I decided to do everything the same
as in the fabric-sample only that I don't install it in docker containers but natively again.
For this I took all configuration files from the fabric sample and wrote or copy/pasted the following script:

**completeNativeScript.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
#

. utils.sh

export PATH=${PWD}/../bin:$PATH
export FABRIC_CFG_PATH=${PWD}/config
export VERBOSE=false

#### Start Fabric-CA ####
echo "Start CA-Org1"
set -x
export FABRIC_CA_HOME=$PWD/organizations/fabric-ca/org1
export FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca-org1
export FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_ENABLED=true
export FABRIC_CA_SERVER_PORT=7054

fabric-ca-server start -b admin:adminpw -d & >logs/CaOrg1Logs.txt
{ set +x; } 2>/dev/null

sleep 10

echo "Start CA-Orderer"
set -x
export FABRIC_CA_HOME=$PWD/organizations/fabric-ca/ordererOrg
export FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca-orderer
export FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_ENABLED=true
export FABRIC_CA_SERVER_PORT=9054

fabric-ca-server start -b admin:adminpw -d & >logs/CaOrdererlogs.txt
{ set +x; } 2>/dev/null

sleep 10

echo "Creating Org1 and Orderer Identities"

. organizations/fabric-ca/registerEnroll.sh

createOrg1

createOrderer

echo "Generating CCP files for Org1"
./organizations/ccp-generate.sh

##### Start Orderer und Peer #####
echo "Start Orderer and Peer"
set -x
export FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=INFO
export ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0
export ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENPORT=7050
export ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPID=OrdererMSP
export ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR=$PWD/organizations/ordererOrganizations/actiware.com/orderers/orderer.actiware.com/msp
export ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ENABLED=true
export ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_PRIVATEKEY=$PWD/organizations/ordererOrganizations/actiware.com/orderers/orderer.actiware.com/tls/server.key
export ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_CERTIFICATE=$PWD/organizations/ordererOrganizations/actiware.com/orderers/orderer.actiware.com/tls/server.crt
export ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ROOTCAS=[$PWD/organizations/ordererOrganizations/actiware.com/orderers/orderer.actiware.com/tls/server.crt]
export ORDERER_KAFKA_TOPIC_REPLICATIONFACTOR=1
export ORDERER_KAFKA_VERBOSE=true
export ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_CLIENTCERTIFICATE=$PWD/organizations/ordererOrganizations/actiware.com/orderers/orderer.actiware.com/tls/server.crt
export ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_CLIENTPRIVATEKEY=$PWD/organizations/ordererOrganizations/actiware.com/orderers/orderer.actiware.com/tls/server.key
export ORDERER_GENERAL_CLUSTER_ROOTCAS=[$PWD/organizations/ordererOrganizations/actiware.com/orderers/orderer.actiware.com/tls/server.crt]
export ORDERER_GENERAL_BOOTSTRAPMETHOD=none
export ORDERER_CHANNELPARTICIPATION_ENABLED=true
export ORDERER_ADMIN_TLS_ENABLED=true
export ORDERER_ADMIN_TLS_CERTIFICATE=$PWD/organizations/ordererOrganizations/actiware.com/orderers/orderer.actiware.com/tls/server.crt
export ORDERER_ADMIN_TLS_PRIVATEKEY=$PWD/organizations/ordererOrganizations/actiware.com/orderers/orderer.actiware.com/tls/server.key
export ORDERER_ADMIN_TLS_ROOTCAS=[$PWD/organizations/ordererOrganizations/actiware.com/orderers/orderer.actiware.com/tls/server.crt]
export ORDERER_ADMIN_TLS_CLIENTROOTCAS=[$PWD/organizations/ordererOrganizations/actiware.com/orderers/orderer.actiware.com/tls/server.crt]
export ORDERER_ADMIN_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:7053

orderer & >logs/ordererlogs.txt

sleep 10

export FABRIC_LOGGING_SPEC=INFO
export CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
export CORE_PEER_PROFILE_ENABLED=true
export CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=$PWD/organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.actiware.com/peers/peer0.org1.actiware.com/tls/server.crt
export CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=$PWD/organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.actiware.com/peers/peer0.org1.actiware.com/tls/server.key
export CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=$PWD/organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.actiware.com/peers/peer0.org1.actiware.com/tls/server.crt
export CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.org1.actiware.com
export CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=localhost:7051
export CORE_PEER_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:7051
export CORE_PEER_CHAINCODEADDRESS=localhost:7052
export CORE_PEER_CHAINCODELISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0:7052
export CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=localhost:7051
export CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=localhost:7051
export CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP

peer node start & >logs/peer0logs.txt
{ set +x; } 2>/dev/null

sleep 10

CREATE_CHANNEL=$(getUserInput "Soll ein Channel erstellt werden? (y/n) ")

if [ $CREATE_CHANNEL == "y" ]; then
    ##### Create Gensisblock, Create and Join Channel #####
    echo "Start to generate the channel"
    CHANNEL_NAME="awchannel"

    set -x
    export FABRIC_CFG_PATH=$PWD/config
    configtxgen -profile TwoOrgsApplicationGenesis -outputBlock ./channel-artifacts/${CHANNEL_NAME}.block -channelID $CHANNEL_NAME

    export ORDERER_CA=${PWD}/organizations/ordererOrganizations/actiware.com/orderers/orderer.actiware.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.actiware.com-cert.pem
    export PEER0_ORG1_CA=${PWD}/organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.actiware.com/peers/peer0.org1.actiware.com/tls/ca.crt
    export ORDERER_ADMIN_TLS_SIGN_CERT=${PWD}/organizations/ordererOrganizations/actiware.com/orderers/orderer.actiware.com/tls/server.crt
    export ORDERER_ADMIN_TLS_PRIVATE_KEY=${PWD}/organizations/ordererOrganizations/actiware.com/orderers/orderer.actiware.com/tls/server.key

    export CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID="Org1MSP"
    export CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
    export CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=$PEER0_ORG1_CA
    export CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=${PWD}/organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.actiware.com/users/Admin@org1.actiware.com/msp
    export CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=localhost:7051

    osnadmin channel join --channelID $CHANNEL_NAME --config-block ./channel-artifacts/${CHANNEL_NAME}.block -o localhost:7053 --ca-file "$ORDERER_CA" --client-cert "$ORDERER_ADMIN_TLS_SIGN_CERT" --client-key "$ORDERER_ADMIN_TLS_PRIVATE_KEY"

    peer channel join -b ./channel-artifacts/${CHANNEL_NAME}.block
    { set +x; } 2>/dev/null

    CREATE_ANCHOR_PEERS=$(getUserInput "Sollen die Anchor Peers erstellt werden? (y/n)")

    if [ $CREATE_ANCHOR_PEERS == "y" ]; then
        #### Set Anchor Peers ####
        echo "fetch channel config"

        set -x 
        peer channel fetch config_block.pb -o localhost:7050 --ordererTLSHostnameOverride orderer.actiware.com -c $CHANNEL_NAME --tls --cafile "$ORDERER_CA"
        { set +x; } 2>/dev/null

        OUTPUT=${CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID}config.json
        echo "Decoding config block to json and isolating config to $OUTPUT"
        set -x
        configtxlator proto_decode --input config_block.pb --type common.Block | jq .data.data[0].payload.data.config >"${OUTPUT}"
        { set +x; } 2>/dev/null

        echo "Modify the configuration to append the anchor peer "
        set -x
        jq '.channel_group.groups.Application.groups.'${CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID}'.values += {"AnchorPeers":{"mod_policy": "Admins","value":{"anchor_peers": [{"host": "localhost","port": "7051"}]},"version": "0"}}' ${CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID}config.json > ${CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID}modified_config.json
        { set +x; } 2>/dev/null

        echo "Create Config Update"

        ORIGINAL=${CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID}config.json
        MODIFIED=${CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID}modified_config.json
        OUTPUT=${CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID}anchors.tx

        set -x
        configtxlator proto_encode --input "${ORIGINAL}" --type common.Config >original_config.pb
        configtxlator proto_encode --input "${MODIFIED}" --type common.Config >modified_config.pb
        configtxlator compute_update --channel_id "${CHANNEL_NAME}" --original original_config.pb --updated modified_config.pb >config_update.pb
        configtxlator proto_decode --input config_update.pb --type common.ConfigUpdate >config_update.json
        echo '{"payload":{"header":{"channel_header":{"channel_id":"'$CHANNEL_NAME'", "type":2}},"data":{"config_update":'$(cat config_update.json)'}}}' | jq . >config_update_in_envelope.json
        configtxlator proto_encode --input config_update_in_envelope.json --type common.Envelope >"${OUTPUT}"
        { set +x; } 2>/dev/null

        echo "Update Anchor Peer"
        peer channel update -o localhost:7050 --ordererTLSHostnameOverride orderer.actiware.com -c $CHANNEL_NAME -f ${CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID}anchors.tx --tls --cafile "$ORDERER_CA"

        DEPLOY_CC=$(getUserInput "Soll der Chaincode deployed werden?(y/n)")
        if [ $DEPLOY_CC == "y" ]; then
            ##### deploy Chaincode #####
            echo "deploy chaincode"
            CC_SRC_PATH=$PWD/StandardContract

            set -x
            export FABRIC_CFG_PATH=$PWD/config

            pushd $CC_SRC_PATH
            GO111MODULE=on go mod vendor
            popd

            peer lifecycle chaincode package packaged_chaincode.tar.gz --path ${CC_SRC_PATH} --lang golang --label ${CHANNEL_NAME}_1.0

            peer lifecycle chaincode install packaged_chaincode.tar.gz

            peer lifecycle chaincode queryinstalled
        fi
    fi
fi
```

**utils.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

function getUserInput() {
    read -p "$1" USER_INPUT
    
    while [ -z "$USER_INPUT" ] || [ "$USER_INPUT" = "NA" ]
    do
        echo "Keine Eingabe erfasst. Bitte versuchen Sie es erneut." >&2
        read -p "$1" USER_INPUT
    done

    echo $USER_INPUT
}

# println echos string
function println() {
  echo -e "$1"
}

# errorln echos i red color
function errorln() {
  println "${C_RED}${1}${C_RESET}"
}

# successln echos in green color
function successln() {
  println "${C_GREEN}${1}${C_RESET}"
}

# infoln echos in blue color
function infoln() {
  println "${C_BLUE}${1}${C_RESET}"
}

# warnln echos in yellow color
function warnln() {
  println "${C_YELLOW}${1}${C_RESET}"
}

# fatalln echos in red color and exits with fail status
function fatalln() {
  errorln "$1"
  exit 1
}

export -f errorln
export -f successln
export -f infoln
export -f warnln
```

The scripts registerEnroll.sh and create-ccp.sh are the same as from the fabric-sample repo.

But I had problems to create the channel on the orderer. I get the error "Bad Certificate". Then I just tried to install the chaincode for fun and it worked...
Unfortunately I can not use this as a solution, because I need the channel. But again the question is how is it possible that this is possible?

I am still a beginner with Hyperledger Fabric.... I am already sure that I made one or more configuration errors somewhere.
Unfortunately I've reached a point where I can't get any further. Maybe someone can help me.
If you have any questions about one of the above attempts or if you need the configuration files, just let me know.

Answer (score 0):

For the first attempt, How about using Docker Swarm to enable communication between containers living in separate hosts?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no experience with Docker Swarm and would have to learn the ropes myself. I was hoping that there would be a solution without directly using Docker Swarm or even Docker Container. In my research regarding this problem, I found solutions in Docker Swarm. However, the functionalities of Swarm are completely unknown to me...

Comment: But the way the situation looks so far. It will probably come down to this

Comment: Docker Swarm is fairly simple to use. All you need is to create a network at a machine, and share the network token with other machines to join them to the wide network. Hope that helps

Comment: Okay but what is, if u had two or more different Organizations... in that case u don't want to manually share the tokens... So Docker Swarm would be not the best Solution for me.. because no one could join my network without the token..

Comment: Honestly, I do not get the logic behind what you are proposing. But a rule of thumb is that network composition has to be established somehow in a trusted manner whether it is manual or automated given that a sort of discovery mechanism is in place. Even Bitcoin nodes have to communicate with DNS seeds first before joining the network. Anyhow, hope you good luck with what ever you want to achieve.